# How to access remote JMS queue from docker weblogic

Tags: docker, jms, jndi, docker-swarm, weblogic12c

We have issue with docker wls12 env connecting external weblogic JMS queue which is hosted in remote WL 11g infrastructure

We are seeing remote jvm shutdown error while trying to connect from docker consumer end.

It looks like from docker env making remote ejb calls not working. any one have any idea on how to fix this ?

Here is the workflow.

`Docker(wls12) --> calling remote JMS jndi queue through t3 protocol--> wls11`

configuration:

```
jms.xx.connfactory=XXX
jms.xx.dest=Q_XX_XX_IN
jms.xx.provider=t3://wls-XXX.com:40391
jms.xx.namingfactory=weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory
```

Errors:

> CAR PROVIDER_URL:
>   t3://XXXX:40391
>
> Could not connect to the WebLogic
>   Server, will retry in 30 seconds. javax.naming.CommunicationException:
>   This RJVM has already been shutdown
>   5901330264972086515S:XXX.com:[40391,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]:XXX.com:40391,XXX:40391,XXX

Tried with adding `-Dweblogic.rjvm.enableprotocolswitch=true` and enabling http tunneling.. no help